# How to change the language for alerts in chosen.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization, jquery-chosen

When you type in an unavailable option in the multiple select box in chosen.js, it will generate the output 'No results match "*query*"'. Is there a way to change the output language?
[image: See the text on the bottom.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set default message for it -

```
// jQuery version: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/example.jquery.html
$(".chzn-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Translated No results matched"});

// Prototype version: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/example.proto.html
new Chosen($$(".chzn-select")[element_index],{no_results_text: "Translated No results matched"});
```

Except this, there doesn't seem to be any i18n support.

Comment: Pretty sure you should send in the DOMNode rater than a jQuery Object.

Comment: @NULL I took the example from their documentation. http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: You are absolutely right. `$('#element').chosen( { no_results_text : 'alternative text' } );` - cannot see why this correct answer is downvoted. You cannot change "language", this is the possibility there is ...

Comment: I have down voted the answer because the 2. example won't work as expected. If you look around in the source you will find that the init in `AbstractChosen ` witch `Chosen` is extented from will try to read `.multiple` from the node send as the first argument. This will fail if a jQuery Object is send. Therefore the multiply example won't work.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Chosen.js says itself in it's docummentation. If you look in the source you will find that i won't work. Don't always trust a doc. headless. Remember the docs is written by people and people can make mistakes.

Comment: And to @davidkonrad you can set the language another way. By overwriting the fallback variable. `AbstractChosen.default_no_result_text`. Again if you look in the source code you will find out that when the default values there is readed from multiply sources: ` AbstractChosen.prototype.set_default_text = ....` ... And at the end: `return this.results_none_found = this.form_field.getAttribute("data-no_results_text") || this.options.no_results_text || AbstractChosen.default_no_result_text;` As you can see the value is last readed from `Abs..Chosen.default.no_..text`.

Comment: Where `this.options.no_results_text` is the init option specified in the 2. argument. Or in the jQuery wrapper the first.

Comment: @NULL, it works - does that myself, `$('#element').chosen( { no_results_text : 'alternative text' } );` for switching between english and danish messages,  cant se why arguing

Comment: @NULL, **and now you are downvoting my posts elsewhere, when you cannot downvote me here**? It is NOT wrong that you cannot change the language, there is no language to change - you can change the messages. Your references to chosen.js, which we all know and can read, is pointless

Comment: @davidkonrad If you <u>read</u> my first comment you will see that I'm only talking about the 2. example. new Chosen(jQuery(selector), {...}). And I have included you bacause you say: ` You cannot change "language", this is the possibility there is ...` Witch is clearly wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30336/discussion-between-null-and-davidkonrad)

Comment: @NULL `This will fail if a jQuery Object is send`, it wont. `.multiple()` will fail, `.multiple` wont. It will return `undefined` which will evaluate to `false` in later conditions.

Comment: @Bibhas Witch isn't expected behavior if you are working on `<select multiply='true'>....</select>`

Answer (score 13):

You're able to change 3 messages. Single selection, Multiple selection and no results text.

```
$('#ID').chosen({
    no_results_text: "Sem resultados para",
    placeholder_text_single: "Selecione uma opção",
    placeholder_text_multiple: "Selecione as opções"
});
```

In this case it has been translated to Portuguese.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the [source code of chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen/chosen.jquery.js) you will find these:

```
AbstractChosen.default_multiple_text = "Select Some Options";

AbstractChosen.default_single_text = "Select an Option";

AbstractChosen.default_no_result_text = "No results match";
```

`AbstractChosen` is using the global namespace so think you can simply say:

```
AbstractChosen.default_no_result_text = 'My default text';
```

---

And be sure to set the `default_no_result_text` before initializing any components.

You can later on overwrite this value on specific components: (Assuming you are using jQuery):

**config.js**

```
AbstractChosen.default_no_result_text = 'default no result text:'
```

**app.js**

```
$(select).chosen({
    no_result_text: 'specific no result text for this component'
});
```

The API is changed and the above wont work

Comment: The correct way is to specify data-placeholder="default text" as attribute for select

Comment: @MarcoMarsala This is answered more than one year ago, at that state `chosens API was different than today. You can see the source code link I post as reference is removed as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you place that line of code in any place, browser console will say:

No way to override default texts globally. You have to specify them for every chosen() call.