# change language of alert box in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an alert box that displays the message "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" every time two or more alert boxes are displaying. I want to change its language to German, how can I do this?

```
<script>
  alert('All fields are required!');
</script>
```

Comment: You want "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" in German? I think that messaged is based on the language pack of the browser.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669592/how-to-change-the-language-for-alerts-in-chosen-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, this is a browser feature. The language depends on the browser language of the user.